# Qt: disable layout mirroring in designer?

Tags: qt, layout, right-to-left

I have  a hebrew locale configured in my computer and for some reason this makes QT designer mirror its entire interface to be aligned from right to left.

This is horrible and makes the designer useless for me.

Is there a way in run-time to make the designer not mirror its GUI elements? a menu item or an environment variable or something?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to run designer with the option "-reverse", that could solve your problem.
If the locale is "french", and I run with "-reverse" all the layouts become right to left aligned, so maybe if the locale is "hebrew", the layouts will become left to right.